# PhpStorm create a new file/folder in relation to the root directory. [Keyboard shortcut]

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm 2017.3

So at the moment I can create a new file in the currently selected directory by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Insert</kbd>. The only problem is if I want to create said file in a different directory I can't because I can not use commands like `~` OR `../`.

Is there anyway keyboard command to create a file in relation to the root directory so if I have the folder structure `/app/models` I could create a new file in a new folder and file by typing `/app/models/auth/User.php`?

Comment: You can browse directory using ALT+HOME and then use ALT+INSERT to create file

Comment: That works, but it seems a bit time consuming and not much of an improvement from moving the mouse. I was hoping for a super quick way to create a file in any directory.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156060 I'm sure some better ticket with more votes/comments exists -- try asking there. As for the actual question -- not possible ATM AFAIK.